# Calling an "external" function from a class method

Tags: c++, class, function, methods

I have a function that I want to call from within a class method. The function is in a file called mergeSort.cpp. Here is a snippet of the .cpp file that the class is implemented in:

```
// other includes
#include "mergeSort.cpp"

// other methods
void Servers::sortSites() {
 mergeSort(server_sites.begin(), server_sites.end(), siteCompare);
}
// remaining methods
```

When I try to compile I get errors saying that mergeSort can't be found. I think this is because it's trying to call Servers::mergeSort. How would I go about calling an external function?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to use the "::" external namespace resolutor:

```
::mergeSort(...);
```

This tells the compiler to look for the function in the outer namespace. If this particular function is defined in another namespace or class, you have to specify it explicitly:

```
Namespace::mergeSort(...);
```

If you don't want to have to resolve the name completely each time you use it, you can import the name into the current namespace by either using:

```
using namespace Namespace;
```

or

```
using Namespace::mergeSort;
```

(where `Namespace` is the name in which `mergeShort()` is defined).

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be a couple of issues here. Firstly, does `Servers::mergeSort` actually exist? You've speculated that it's looking for that, but you haven't actually said that there is such a thing. If there isn't, that's not the problem. In that case, a likely reason it can't see mergeSort would be that it's not in the global namespace (as other answers have speculated). If `Servers::mergeSort` does exist, then see Diego's answer.

A separate issue is -- are you including the .cpp file (which is generally a bit odd) because mergeSort is a template? If no, you should probably be including the accompanying .h I guess. If yes, a more usual pattern is to include the file with the template code in the header, like so:

```
// mergeSort.h
// <Begin include guard

// <Lots of header stuff>

#include "mergeSort.tpp"

// <End include guard>
```

Then you include mergeSort.h elsewhere, and it's one thing less for clients to remember.

Answer (score 0):

Check if `mergeSort()` is in a particular [namespace](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/namespaces/).